# Can You Get the Txn Hash From a PairCreated Event?

Tags: ethers.js

When searching for newly created tokens using `factory.on("PairCreated", async (token0, token1, addressPair)` is there any way to get the Txn Hash of each new pair to use in conjunction with `.getTransactionReceipt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to get the Txn Hash of each new pair to use in
> conjunction with `.getTransactionReceipt` ?

Yes, just use :

```
factory.on("PairCreated", async (token0, token1, addressPair, event) => {});
```

And you can read the tx hash in `event.transactionHash` or call `event.getTransactionReceipt` directly.