# How To Convert Pancakeswap Pair ID into Txn Hash?

Tags: ethers.js

How to get the Transaction Hash of a Pancakeswap Pair ID?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense a pancake pair doesn't have a transaction hash. Do you want the transaction hash when the pair was created?

Comment: Exactly! The end goal is to use the Transaction Hash with getTransactionReceipt() to filter new contracts.

Comment: According to my previous question (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114695/can-you-get-the-txn-hash-from-a-paircreated-event/114698#114698), this is possible, but I have tried everything I know how and could not find any additional documentation regarding this online.

Comment: The event parameter in the callback `factory.on("PairCreated", async (token0, token1, addressPair, event) => { let tx = await event.getTransaction(); })` has a getTransaction() and getTransactionRecipient(), see [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L95-L96).

Comment: Just tried that and received: "event.getTransaction is not a function". I will keep looking for now as it might just be something simple that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want the transaction hash of the transaction that created the pair programmatically.

When a pair is created, the event `PairCreated` is fired by the factory. What you want to do is find those events and get the transaction hash from the event object.

**For past events**

You can use the [getPastLogs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0-rc.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs) function. The topic to look for is `0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9`, which is the topic of the `PairCreated` event (I got it by looking at a transaction in bscscan). The address is the Factory's contract address.

```
web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    address: "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73",
    topics: ["0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9"]
})
.then(function(events) {
    let arrayOfHashes = events.map(event => event.transactionHash);
    console.log(arrayOfHashes);
});
```

Once you have the event, look for the `transactionHash`.

**For future events**

You want to subscribe to events with [subscribe("logs")](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0-rc.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs). It works similarly to `getPastEvents`.

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73',
    topics: ['0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.transactionHash);
});
```

Comment: To have a complete answer having a sample code will be great.

Comment: I added examples.